# Plotting a decision boundary separating 2 classes using Matplotlib's pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I could really use a tip to help me plotting a decision boundary to separate to classes of data. I created some sample data (from a Gaussian distribution) via Python NumPy. In this case, every data point is a 2D coordinate, i.e., a 1 column vector consisting of 2 rows. E.g.,

```
[ 1
  2 ]
```

Let's assume I have 2 classes, class1 and class2, and I created 100 data points for class1 and 100 data points for class2 via the code below (assigned to the variables x1_samples and x2_samples).

```
mu_vec1 = np.array([0,0])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[2,0],[0,2]])
x1_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 100)
mu_vec1 = mu_vec1.reshape(1,2).T # to 1-col vector

mu_vec2 = np.array([1,2])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
x2_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 100)
mu_vec2 = mu_vec2.reshape(1,2).T
```

When I plot the data points for each class, it would look like this:

[image]

Now, I came up with an equation for an decision boundary to separate both classes and would like to add it to the plot. However, I am not really sure how I can plot this function:

```
def decision_boundary(x_vec, mu_vec1, mu_vec2):
    g1 = (x_vec-mu_vec1).T.dot((x_vec-mu_vec1))
    g2 = 2*( (x_vec-mu_vec2).T.dot((x_vec-mu_vec2)) )
    return g1 - g2
```

I would really appreciate any help!

EDIT:
Intuitively (If I did my math right) I would expect the decision boundary to look somewhat like this red line when I plot the function...

[image]

Comment: What is the `x_vec` in the `decision_boundary` function supposed to be? Are you just trying to plot a line separating the two classes?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right know, but it sounds like you want the 0 contour of `decision_boundary`.  It's easiest to just evaluate the function on a regular grid and contour the result. Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, should be a line, I uploaded an example img to the original question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those were some great suggestions, thanks a lot for your help! I ended up solving the equation analytically and this is the solution I ended up with (I just want to post it for future reference:

[image]

```py
# 2-category classification with random 2D-sample data 
# from a multivariate normal distribution 

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def decision_boundary(x_1):
    """ Calculates the x_2 value for plotting the decision boundary."""
    return 4 - np.sqrt(-x_1**2 + 4*x_1 + 6 + np.log(16))

# Generating a Gaussion dataset:
# creating random vectors from the multivariate normal distribution 
# given mean and covariance 
mu_vec1 = np.array([0,0])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[2,0],[0,2]])
x1_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 100)
mu_vec1 = mu_vec1.reshape(1,2).T # to 1-col vector

mu_vec2 = np.array([1,2])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
x2_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 100)
mu_vec2 = mu_vec2.reshape(1,2).T # to 1-col vector

# Main scatter plot and plot annotation
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.scatter(x1_samples[:,0], x1_samples[:,1], marker='o', color='green', s=40, alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(x2_samples[:,0], x2_samples[:,1], marker='^', color='blue', s=40, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(['Class1 (w1)', 'Class2 (w2)'], loc='upper right') 
plt.title('Densities of 2 classes with 25 bivariate random patterns each')
plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.xlabel('x1')
ftext = 'p(x|w1) ~ N(mu1=(0,0)^t, cov1=I)\np(x|w2) ~ N(mu2=(1,1)^t, cov2=I)'
plt.figtext(.15,.8, ftext, fontsize=11, ha='left')

# Adding decision boundary to plot
x_1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
bound = decision_boundary(x_1)
plt.plot(x_1, bound, 'r--', lw=3)

x_vec = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim())
x_1 = np.arange(0, 100, 0.05)

plt.show()
```

And the code can be found [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/matplotlib-gallery/blob/master/ipynb/scatterplots.ipynb#Scatter-plot-of-2-classes-with-decision-boundary)

EDIT:

I also have a convenience function for plotting decision regions for classifiers that implement a `fit` and `predict` method, e.g., the classifiers in scikit-learn, which is useful if the solution cannot be found analytically. A more detailed description how it works can be found [here](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/plotting/plot_decision_regions/).

[image]

Comment: how do you know analytically that desicion function is `4 - np.sqrt(-x_1**2 + 4*x_1 + 6 + np.log(16))` ?

Comment: for such a curve can try `clf = SVC(kernel='poly')` if need to solve a Supervised problem

Answer (score 53):

Your question is more complicated than a simple plot : you need to draw the contour which will maximize the inter-class distance. Fortunately it's a well-studied field, particularly for SVM machine learning.

The easiest method is to download the [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) module, which provides a lot of cool methods to draw boundaries: [`scikit-learn`: Support Vector Machines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

Code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy
from sklearn import svm


mu_vec1 = np.array([0,0])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[2,0],[0,2]])
x1_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 100)
mu_vec1 = mu_vec1.reshape(1,2).T # to 1-col vector

mu_vec2 = np.array([1,2])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
x2_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 100)
mu_vec2 = mu_vec2.reshape(1,2).T


fig = plt.figure()


plt.scatter(x1_samples[:,0],x1_samples[:,1], marker='+')
plt.scatter(x2_samples[:,0],x2_samples[:,1], c= 'green', marker='o')

X = np.concatenate((x1_samples,x2_samples), axis = 0)
Y = np.array([0]*100 + [1]*100)

C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'linear',  gamma=0.7, C=C )
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

### [Linear Plot](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_margin.html)

---

```
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (clf.intercept_[0]) / w[1]

plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
```

[image]

### [MultiLinear Plot](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/0.5/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html)

---

```
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'rbf',  gamma=0.7, C=C )
clf.fit(X, Y)

h = .02  # step size in the mesh
# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))


# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
```

[image]

### Implementation

If you want to implement it yourself, you need to solve the following quadratic equation:
[image: boundary equation]

The Wikipedia article

Unfortunately, for non-linear boundaries like the one you draw, it's a difficult problem relying on a kernel trick but there isn't a clear cut solution.

Comment: +1 for thorough answer. However, for the OP's requirements SVM might be overkill. Since the data comes from two normal distributions with different mean and covariances the decision boundary is quadratic. A QDA classifier might be sufficient (see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.qda.QDA.html).

Comment: Can you please explain slope and intercept calculation from the "Linear plot" section?

Answer (score 25):

Based on the way you've written `decision_boundary` you'll want to use the `contour` function, as Joe noted above. If you just want the boundary line, you can draw a single contour at the 0 level:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
c1, c2 = "#3366AA", "#AA3333"
ax.scatter(*x1_samples.T, c=c1, s=40)
ax.scatter(*x2_samples.T, c=c2, marker="D", s=40)
x_vec = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim())
ax.contour(x_vec, x_vec,
           decision_boundary(x_vec, mu_vec1, mu_vec2),
           levels=[0], cmap="Greys_r")
```

Which makes:

[image]

Comment: Should the decision boundary not bend around the class with lower variance?

Comment: Yes, you were right. I went back and solved the equation analytically. I will post it as an answer below

Answer (score 13):

You can create your own equation for the boundary:

[image]

where you have to find the positions `x0` and `y0`, as well as the constants `ai` and `bi` for the radius equation. So, you have `2*(n+1)+2` variables. Using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` is straightforward for this type of problem.

The code attached below builds the residual for the `leastsq` penalizing the points outsize the boundary. The result for your problem, obtained with:

```
x, y = find_boundary(x2_samples[:,0], x2_samples[:,1], n)
ax.plot(x, y, '-k', lw=2.)

x, y = find_boundary(x1_samples[:,0], x1_samples[:,1], n)
ax.plot(x, y, '--k', lw=2.)
```

using `n=1`:
[image]

using `n=2`:

[image]

usng `n=5`:
[image]

using `n=7`:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos, pi
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def find_boundary(x, y, n, plot_pts=1000):

    def sines(theta):
        ans = np.array([sin(i*theta)  for i in range(n+1)])
        return ans

    def cosines(theta):
        ans = np.array([cos(i*theta)  for i in range(n+1)])
        return ans

    def residual(params, x, y):
        x0 = params[0]
        y0 = params[1]
        c = params[2:]

        r_pts = ((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2)**0.5

        thetas = np.arctan2((y-y0), (x-x0))
        m = np.vstack((sines(thetas), cosines(thetas))).T
        r_bound = m.dot(c)

        delta = r_pts - r_bound
        delta[delta>0] *= 10

        return delta

    # initial guess for x0 and y0
    x0 = x.mean()
    y0 = y.mean()

    params = np.zeros(2 + 2*(n+1))
    params[0] = x0
    params[1] = y0
    params[2:] += 1000

    popt, pcov = leastsq(residual, x0=params, args=(x, y),
                         ftol=1.e-12, xtol=1.e-12)

    thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, plot_pts)
    m = np.vstack((sines(thetas), cosines(thetas))).T
    c = np.array(popt[2:])
    r_bound = m.dot(c)
    x_bound = popt[0] + r_bound*cos(thetas)
    y_bound = popt[1] + r_bound*sin(thetas)

    return x_bound, y_bound
```

Answer (score 6):

I like the mglearn library to draw decision boundaries. Here is one example from the book "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python" by A. Mueller:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 3))
for n_neighbors, ax in zip([1, 3, 9], axes):
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors).fit(X, y)
    mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(clf, X, fill=True, eps=0.5, ax=ax, alpha=.4)
    mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title("{} neighbor(s)".format(n_neighbors))
    ax.set_xlabel("feature 0")
    ax.set_ylabel("feature 1")
axes[0].legend(loc=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use scikit learn, you can write your code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# read data
data = pd.read_csv('ex2data1.txt', header=None)
X = data[[0,1]].values
y = data[2]


# use LogisticRegression
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X, y)

# Coefficient of the features in the decision function. (from theta 1 to theta n)
parameters = log_reg.coef_[0]
# Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added to the decision function. (theta 0)
parameter0 = log_reg.intercept_

# Plotting the decision boundary
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
x_values = [np.min(X[:, 1] -5 ), np.max(X[:, 1] +5 )]
# calcul y values
y_values = np.dot((-1./parameters[1]), (np.dot(parameters[0],x_values) + parameter0))
colors=['red' if l==0 else 'blue' for l in y]
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], label='Logistics regression', color=colors)
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label='Decision Boundary')
plt.show()
```

[image: decision boundary]

see: [Building-a-Logistic-Regression-with-Scikit-learn](https://github.com/anasmorahhib/Python-for-Data-Science/tree/master/ex4-Building-a-Logistic-Regression-with-Scikit-learn)

Answer (score 2):

Just solved a very similar problem with a different approach (root finding) and wanted to post this alternative as answer here for future reference:

```
   def discr_func(x, y, cov_mat, mu_vec):
        """
        Calculates the value of the discriminant function for a dx1 dimensional
        sample given covariance matrix and mean vector.

        Keyword arguments:
            x_vec: A dx1 dimensional numpy array representing the sample.
            cov_mat: numpy array of the covariance matrix.
            mu_vec: dx1 dimensional numpy array of the sample mean.

        Returns a float value as result of the discriminant function.

        """
        x_vec = np.array([[x],[y]])

        W_i = (-1/2) * np.linalg.inv(cov_mat)
        assert(W_i.shape[0] > 1 and W_i.shape[1] > 1), 'W_i must be a matrix'

        w_i = np.linalg.inv(cov_mat).dot(mu_vec)
        assert(w_i.shape[0] > 1 and w_i.shape[1] == 1), 'w_i must be a column vector'

        omega_i_p1 = (((-1/2) * (mu_vec).T).dot(np.linalg.inv(cov_mat))).dot(mu_vec)
        omega_i_p2 = (-1/2) * np.log(np.linalg.det(cov_mat))
        omega_i = omega_i_p1 - omega_i_p2
        assert(omega_i.shape == (1, 1)), 'omega_i must be a scalar'

        g = ((x_vec.T).dot(W_i)).dot(x_vec) + (w_i.T).dot(x_vec) + omega_i
        return float(g)

    #g1 = discr_func(x, y, cov_mat=cov_mat1, mu_vec=mu_vec_1)
    #g2 = discr_func(x, y, cov_mat=cov_mat2, mu_vec=mu_vec_2)

    x_est50 = list(np.arange(-6, 6, 0.1))
    y_est50 = []
    for i in x_est50:
        y_est50.append(scipy.optimize.bisect(lambda y: discr_func(i, y, cov_mat=cov_est_1, mu_vec=mu_est_1) - \
                          discr_func(i, y, cov_mat=cov_est_2, mu_vec=mu_est_2), -10,10))
    y_est50 = [float(i) for i in y_est50]
```

Here is the result:
(blue the quadratic case, red the linear case (equal variances)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTrz4.png]

Answer (score 1):

i use this method from this book **python-machine-learning-2nd.pdf** [URL](http://diggerdnepr.ddns.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/python-machine-learning-2nd.pdf)

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, test_idx=None, resolution=0.02):

    # setup marker generator and color map
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    # plot the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
                           np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.3, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], 
                    y=X[y == cl, 1],
                    alpha=0.8, 
                    c=colors[idx],
                    marker=markers[idx], 
                    label=cl, 
                    edgecolor='black')

    # highlight test samples
    if test_idx:
        # plot all samples
        X_test, y_test = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]

        plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0],
                    X_test[:, 1],
                    c='',
                    edgecolor='black',
                    alpha=1.0,
                    linewidth=1,
                    marker='o',
                    s=100, 
                    label='test set')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered in a very thorough way analytically. I just wanted to share a possible 'hack' to the problem. It is unwieldy but gets the job done.

Start by building a mesh grid of the 2d area and then based on the classifier just build a class map of the entire space. Subsequently detect changes in the decision made row-wise and store the edges points in a list and scatter plot the points.

```
def disc(x):   # returns the class of the point based on location x = [x,y]
     temp = 0.5  + 0.5*np.sign(disc0(x)-disc1(x)) 
# disc0() and disc1() are the discriminant functions of the respective classes
     return 0*temp + 1*(1-temp) 

num = 200
a = np.linspace(-4,4,num)
b = np.linspace(-6,6,num)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(a,b)

def decColor(x,y):
     temp = np.zeros((num,num))
     print x.shape, np.size(x,axis=0)
     for l in range(num):
         for m in range(num):
             p = np.array([x[l,m],y[l,m]])
             #print p
             temp[l,m] = disc(p)
     return temp
boundColorMap = decColor(X,Y)

group = 0
boundary = []
for x in range(num):
    group = boundColorMap[x,0]
    for y in range(num):
        if boundColorMap[x,y]!=group:
            boundary.append([X[x,y],Y[x,y]])
            group = boundColorMap[x,y]  
boundary = np.array(boundary)
```

[Sample Decision Boundary for a simple bivariate gaussian classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DfYx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Given two bi-variate normal distributions, you can use Gaussian Discriminant Analysis (GDA) to come up with a decision boundary as the difference between the log of the 2 pdf's.

Here's a way to do it using scipy multivariate_normal (the code is not optimized):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy.linalg import inv
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis

def normal_scatter(mean, cov, p):

  size = 100
  sigma_x = cov[0,0]
  sigma_y = cov[1,1]
  mu_x = mean[0]
  mu_y = mean[1]

  x_ps, y_ps = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size).T


  x,y = np.mgrid[mu_x-3*sigma_x:mu_x+3*sigma_x:1/size, mu_y-3*sigma_y:mu_y+3*sigma_y:1/size]
  grid = np.empty(x.shape + (2,))
  grid[:, :, 0] = x; grid[:, :, 1] = y


  z = p*multivariate_normal.pdf(grid, mean, cov)

  return x_ps, y_ps, x,y,z

# Dist 1
mu_1 = np.array([1, 1])
cov_1 = .5*np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
p_1 = .5
x_ps, y_ps, x,y,z = normal_scatter(mu_1, cov_1, p_1)
plt.plot(x_ps,y_ps,'x')
plt.contour(x, y, z, cmap='Blues', levels=3)

# Dist 2
mu_2 = np.array([2, 1])
#cov_2 = np.array([[2, -1], [-1, 1]])
cov_2 = cov_1
p_2 = .5
x_ps, y_ps, x,y,z = normal_scatter(mu_2, cov_2, p_2)
plt.plot(x_ps,y_ps,'.')
plt.contour(x, y, z, cmap='Oranges', levels=3)

# Decision Boundary
X = np.empty(x.shape + (2,))
X[:, :, 0] = x; X[:, :, 1] = y
g = np.log(p_1*multivariate_normal.pdf(X, mu_1, cov_1)) - np.log(p_2*multivariate_normal.pdf(X, mu_2, cov_2))

plt.contour(x, y, g, [0])

plt.grid()
plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='k')
plt.plot([mu_1[0], mu_2[0]], [mu_1[1], mu_2[1]], 'k')
plt.show()
```

If p_1 != p_2, then you get non-linear boundary. The decision boundary is given by `g` above.

Then to plot the decision hyper-plane (line in 2D), you need to evaluate `g` for a 2D mesh, then get the contour which will give a separating line.

You can also assume to have equal co-variance matrices for both distributions, which will give a linear decision boundary. In this case, you can replace the calculation of `g` in the above code with the following:

```
W = inv(cov_1).dot(mu_1-mu_2)


x_0 = 1/2*(mu_1+mu_2) - cov_1.dot(np.log(p_1/p_2)).dot((mu_1-mu_2)/mahalanobis(mu_1, mu_2, cov_1))
X = np.empty(x.shape + (2,))
X[:, :, 0] = x; X[:, :, 1] = y

g = (X-x_0).dot(W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.1, sklearn has a function for this:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay

Comment: [example of its use](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-isolation-forest-py) in Isolation Forest for Outliers detection