# Decision Boundary with three dataset in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am trying to determine discriminant function and plot decision boundary for a given data set. My data set has three observations, lets say X1, X2 and X3 with two features. I was able to plot the data set as shown below

[image: Plot of Training data]

Now I am able to calculate the mean and covariance of the data and hence come up with P(x|C) function. But when I try to plot this function using following method, I get wrong results.

[image: Decision]

I am using following way to plot the decision boundry:

```
x_min, x_max = XX[:, 0].min() - 1, XX[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = XX[:, 1].min() - 1, XX[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = meshgrid(arange(x_min, x_max, .02),
                     arange(y_min, y_max, .02))
Z = A*(xx**2)-B*(yy**2)-C*xx*yy-D*xx-E*yy+F
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z)
```

I would appreciate any guidance in correcting my mistakes.

Thanks in Advance.

Shashank

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot

Comment: Depending on what A, B, etc. are, the surfaces you have plotted are perfectly viable results from the functional form for Z you have there, so I don't think there's any issue with the plotting.

Comment: Sorry guys for delay in responding back. I did not get notification of your replies somehow. Thanks a lot for help.