# plotting decision boundary of logistic regression

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm implementing logistic regression. I managed to get probabilities out of it, and am able to predict a 2 class classification task.

My question is:

For my final model, I have weights and the training data. There are 2 features, so my weight is a vector with 2 rows.

How do I plot this? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot/22356267#22356267), but I don't quite understand the answer. Do I need a contour plot?

Answer (score 55):

An advantage of the logistic regression classifier is that once you fit it, you can get probabilities for any sample vector. That may be more interesting to plot. Here's an example using scikit-learn:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
```

First, generate the data and fit the classifier to the training set:

```
X, y = make_classification(200, 2, 2, 0, weights=[.5, .5], random_state=15)
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X[:100], y[:100])
```

Next, make a continuous grid of values and evaluate the probability of each (x, y) point in the grid:

```
xx, yy = np.mgrid[-5:5:.01, -5:5:.01]
grid = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
probs = clf.predict_proba(grid)[:, 1].reshape(xx.shape)
```

Now, plot the probability grid as a contour map and additionally show the test set samples on top of it:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
contour = ax.contourf(xx, yy, probs, 25, cmap="RdBu",
                      vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax_c = f.colorbar(contour)
ax_c.set_label("$P(y = 1)$")
ax_c.set_ticks([0, .25, .5, .75, 1])

ax.scatter(X[100:,0], X[100:, 1], c=y[100:], s=50,
           cmap="RdBu", vmin=-.2, vmax=1.2,
           edgecolor="white", linewidth=1)

ax.set(aspect="equal",
       xlim=(-5, 5), ylim=(-5, 5),
       xlabel="$X_1$", ylabel="$X_2$")
```

[image]

The logistic regression lets your classify new samples based on any threshold you want, so it doesn't inherently have one "decision boundary." But, of course, a common decision rule to use is p = .5. We can also just draw that contour level using the above code:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.contour(xx, yy, probs, levels=[.5], cmap="Greys", vmin=0, vmax=.6)

ax.scatter(X[100:,0], X[100:, 1], c=y[100:], s=50,
           cmap="RdBu", vmin=-.2, vmax=1.2,
           edgecolor="white", linewidth=1)

ax.set(aspect="equal",
       xlim=(-5, 5), ylim=(-5, 5),
       xlabel="$X_1$", ylabel="$X_2$")
```

[image]

Comment: Am I right that you have imported `seaborn` but actually haven't used it in your answer? I am not familiar with that library, just checking whether it is necessary for the answer.

Comment: @Zhubarb: Seaborn overrides many of the default configurations of matplotlib as soon as you import it.  So if you don't need any functionality that seaborn provides directly, but just want matplotlib to look MUCH better than it does by default, all you have to do is inport seaborn and go about your business with matplotlib

Comment: @Gus I get an error at `probs = clf.predict_probs(grid)[:, 1].reshape(xx.shape)` saying that `AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'predict_probs'` am I missing something?

Comment: if this helps anyone, check out the sklearn example here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html

Comment: @iam.Carrot it's `predict_proba`, *not* `predict_probs`.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is nice for this, but it can also be useful especially when trying to understand what the weights mean, to convert the weights into slope/ intercept form and just draw the decision boundary.

The logits are the form `wx + b` but in the case of binary classification `x` and `w` are two-dimensional. And one of those `x` values actually represents `y` on the plot. This means the equation of the line will look like:

```
w[1] * y = w[0] * x + b 
# to solve for y
y = (w[0] * x)/w[1] + b / w[1]
```

Plotting that where `x_np` is your data and `w` + `b` are your learned parameters the will be something as simple as:

```
plt.scatter(x_np[:,0], x_np[:,1], c=y_np.reshape(-1),cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.autoscale(False)
x_vals = np.array(ax.get_xlim())
y_vals = -(x_vals * w_guess[0] + b_guess[0])/w_guess[1]
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '--', c="red")
```

[image]

Comment: where are you getting `y_vals = -(x_vals * w_guess[0] + b_guess[0])/w_guess[1]`? I'm not seeing how that comes from the original equation to solve for y

Comment: Yeah.. where are you getting that from?

Comment: @YuChen That's what you get when you solve for `y`, where `h(x, y) = 0.5`. Here, `h(x, y)` is the probability function for logistic regression, that means `h(x, y) = 1/(1 + exp(-(w1*x + w2*y + b)))`. So, when this decision function equals `0.5`, that essentially means this instance, `(x, y)`, has a 50% chance of being in class `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
w[1] * y = w[0] * x + b
```

should be:

```
w[1] * y = **-**(w[0] * x + b)
```

As you did in the code:

```
y_vals = -(x_vals * w_guess[0] + b_guess[0])/w_guess[1]
```