# Plot Decision Boundary for Scikit Logistic Regression with 7 Features

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm implementing binary logistic regression with 7 features in Python with scikit-learn, and I want to plot the decision boundary for it (preferably in Matplotlib). I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256058/plotting-decision-boundary-of-logistic-regression) and [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot/22356267#22356267), but none of those work for me when I try to implement them; some require me to only train the model on two features, which I would not prefer.

Ideally, I would like to plot the boundary in both 2d and 3d,
[image: 2d]

[image: 3d]

but either would be fine.

Comment: seems like what I was trying to solve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959066/plot-decision-boundary-for-logistic-regression)

Answer (score 0):

You can not visualize data in dimensions greater than 3, as it is really hard to plot points that have more than 3 dimensions. Using color / hue maybe you get get up to 4 or 5.
So even visualizing your data is impossible, let alone a decision function in this dimension.
What do you mean by plotting the boundary in 2d or 3d?

Comment: Of course, I can't visualize it in 3+ dimensions, so I only want to plot two or three dimensions, and visualize the decision function within that, while still taking into consideration the other 4 or 5 unplotted dimensions (though I know I cannot necessarily plot them).

Comment: Sorry,  I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.