# Plot decision boundary for logistic regression

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to implement logistic regression. I have mapped the features to a polynomial of the form x1^2*x2^0 + x1^1*x2^1 + ... Now I want to plot the decision boundary for the same.
After going through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356551/1783688) I wrote the below code to use the contour function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def map_features(x, degree):
    x_old = x.copy()
    x = pd.DataFrame({"intercept" : [1]*x.shape[0]})
    column_index = 1
    for i in range(1, degree+1):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            x.insert(column_index, str(x_old.columns[1]) + "^" + str(i-j) + str(x_old.columns[2]) + "^" + str(j), np.multiply(x_old.iloc[:,1]**(i-j), x_old.iloc[:,2]**(j)))
            column_index+=1
    return x

def normalize_features(x):
    for column_name in x.columns[1:]:
        mean = x[column_name].mean()
        std = x[column_name].std()
        x[column_name] = (x[column_name] - mean) / std
    return x

def normalize_features2(x):
    for column_name in x.columns[1:-1]:
        mean = x[column_name].mean()
        std = x[column_name].std()
        x[column_name] = (x[column_name] - mean) / std
    return x

def sigmoid(z):
    # print(z)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def predict(x):
    global theta
    probability = np.asscalar(sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta)))
    if(probability >= 0.5):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def predict2(x):
    global theta
    probability = np.asscalar(sigmoid(np.dot(x.T,theta)))
    if(probability >= 0.5):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def cost(x, y, theta):
    m = x.shape[0]
    h_theta = pd.DataFrame(sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta)))
    cost = 1/m * ((-np.multiply(y,h_theta.apply(np.log)) - np.multiply(1-y, (1-h_theta).apply(np.log))).sum())
    return cost

def gradient_descent(x, y, theta):
    global cost_values
    m = x.shape[0]
    iterations = 1000
    alpha = 0.03
    cost_values = pd.DataFrame({'iteration' : [0], 'cost' : [cost(x,y,theta)]})

    for iteration in range(0,iterations):
        theta_old = theta.copy()
        theta.iloc[0,0] = theta.iloc[0,0] - (alpha/m) * np.asscalar((sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta_old)) - y).sum())
        for i in range(1,theta.shape[0]):
            theta.iloc[i,0] = theta.iloc[i,0] - (alpha/m) * np.asscalar(np.multiply((sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta_old)) - y), pd.DataFrame(x.iloc[:,i])).sum())
        c = cost(x,y,theta)
        cost_values = cost_values.append({"iteration" : iteration, "cost" : c}, ignore_index=True)


### Read train data
train_data = pd.read_csv("ex2data1.csv", names = ["exam1", "exam2", "admit"])

### Add intercept column
train_data.insert(0, "intercept", 1)

### Create input data
x = train_data.loc[:,"intercept":"exam2"]
# print(x.head())
x = map_features(x, 2) #map polynomial features
# print(x.head())
x = normalize_features(x) #normalize features
# print(x.head())
y = pd.DataFrame(train_data.loc[:,"admit"])
theta = pd.DataFrame({"theta" : [0] * len(x.columns)})

### Test cost of initial theta
# print(x.shape)
# print(theta.shape)
# print(np.dot(x,theta))
# print(cost(x,y,theta))

### Perform Gradient Descent
gradient_descent(x, y, theta)
# print(theta)
# print(cost(x,y,theta))

### Plot iteration vs Cost
plt.scatter(cost_values["iteration"], cost_values["cost"])
plt.show()

### Calculate Accuracy
acc = 0
for i in range(0,x.shape[0]):
    p = predict(x.iloc[i,:])
    actual = y.iloc[i,0]
    if(p == actual):
        acc+=1
print((acc/x.shape[0]) * 100)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1), np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1))
xx = pd.DataFrame(x_grid.ravel(), columns=["exam1"])
yy = pd.DataFrame(y_grid.ravel(), columns=["exam2"])
z = pd.DataFrame({"intercept" : [1]*xx.shape[0]})
z["exam1"] = xx
z["exam2"] = yy
z = map_features(z,2)
z = normalize_features(z)
p = z.apply(lambda row: predict2(pd.DataFrame(row)), axis=1)
p = np.array(p.values)
p = p.reshape(x_grid.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
train_data = normalize_features2(train_data)
ax.scatter(train_data[train_data["admit"] == 0]["exam1"], train_data[train_data["admit"] == 0]["exam2"],marker="o")
ax.scatter(train_data[train_data["admit"] == 1]["exam1"], train_data[train_data["admit"] == 1]["exam2"],marker="x")
ax.contour(x_grid, y_grid, p, levels=[0])
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Below is the figure I get as output

[image]

I am not sure if im interprettng this correctly but the line should be more of a curve separating the two classes.
The dataset is here [ex2data1.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H5zHraHDWXXBEW341S1KbjhxdhQa8J1e)

Comment: When you post a question, make sure others can simply copy, paste your code and get the same error/output as you are facing. Your code is no good as you don't include the import commands. People will have to do extra research googling how to import things like `map_features `, `normalize_features`... Plz edit your code. Also include your data

Comment: Thanks. just updated it with the full code and added the dataset as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i was able to fix the issue. The issues were:

- the space I was plotting my data on. My previous meshgrid was from the range -3 to 3 with a 0.1 increment. I changed this to use my training data range limits. (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max)
- I was also normalizing my training data when plotting it for my decision boundary. I removed this and plotted the original data points. (not sure if this was causing a problem)
- the z values I was using were the class values. I changed this to use the probability values obtained from the sigmoid function so that I can use the levels parameter.

Below is the working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

def map_features(x, degree):
    x_old = x.copy()
    x = pd.DataFrame({"intercept" : [1]*x.shape[0]})
    column_index = 1
    for i in range(1, degree+1):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            x.insert(column_index, str(x_old.columns[1]) + "^" + str(i-j) + str(x_old.columns[2]) + "^" + str(j), np.multiply(x_old.iloc[:,1]**(i-j), x_old.iloc[:,2]**(j)))
            column_index+=1
    return x

def normalize_features(x):
    global mean_values
    global std_values
    for column_name in x.columns[1:]:
        mean = x[column_name].mean()
        std = x[column_name].std()
        x[column_name] = (x[column_name] - mean) / std
        mean_values[column_name] = mean
        std_values[column_name] = std
    return x

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def cost(x, y, theta):
    m = x.shape[0]
    h_theta = pd.DataFrame(sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta)))
    cost = 1/m * ((-np.multiply(y,h_theta.apply(np.log)) - np.multiply(1-y, (1-h_theta).apply(np.log))).sum())
    return np.asscalar(cost)

def gradient_descent(x, y, theta):
    global cost_values
    m = x.shape[0]
    iterations = 1000
    alpha = 0.03
    cost_values = pd.DataFrame({'iteration' : [0], 'cost' : [cost(x,y,theta)]})

    for iteration in range(0,iterations):
        theta_old = theta.copy()
        theta.iloc[0,0] = theta.iloc[0,0] - (alpha/m) * np.asscalar((sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta_old)) - y).sum())
        for i in range(1,theta.shape[0]):
            theta.iloc[i,0] = theta.iloc[i,0] - (alpha/m) * np.asscalar(np.multiply((sigmoid(np.dot(x,theta_old)) - y), pd.DataFrame(x.iloc[:,i])).sum())
        c = cost(x,y,theta)
        cost_values = cost_values.append({"iteration" : iteration, "cost" : c}, ignore_index=True)

def predict(x):
    global theta
    probability = np.asscalar(sigmoid(np.dot(x.T,theta)))
    return probability
    if(probability >= 0.5):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

### Read train data
train_data = pd.read_csv("ex2data1.csv", names = ["exam1", "exam2", "admit"])

### Create input data
x = train_data.loc[:,"exam1":"exam2"]
### Add intercept column
x.insert(0, "intercept", 1)
mean_values = {}
std_values = {}
mapping_degree = 2
x = normalize_features(x) #normalize features
x = map_features(x, mapping_degree) #map polynomial features
y = pd.DataFrame(train_data.loc[:,"admit"])
theta = pd.DataFrame({"theta" : [0] * len(x.columns)})

### Test cost of initial theta
# print(cost(x,y,theta))

### Perform Gradient Descent
gradient_descent(x, y, theta)
# print(theta)
# print("Cost: " + str(cost(x,y,theta)))

### Plot iteration vs Cost
plt.scatter(cost_values["iteration"], cost_values["cost"])
plt.show()

### Predict an example
student = pd.DataFrame({"exam1": [52], "exam2":[63]})
student.insert(0, "intercept", 1)
#normalizing
for column_name in student.columns[1:]:
    student[column_name] = (student[column_name] - mean_values[column_name]) / std_values[column_name]
student = map_features(student, mapping_degree)
print("probability of admission: " + str(predict(student.T)))

### Calculate Accuracy
acc = 0
for i in range(0,x.shape[0]):
    p = predict(pd.DataFrame(x.iloc[i,:]))
    actual = y.iloc[i,0]
    if(p >= 0.5):
        p = 1
    else:
        p = 0
    if(p == actual):
        acc+=1
print("Accuracy : " + str((acc/x.shape[0]) * 100))

### Plot decision boundary
x_min = train_data["exam1"].min()
x_max = train_data["exam1"].max()
y_min = train_data["exam2"].min()
y_max = train_data["exam2"].max()
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 1), np.arange(y_min, y_max, 1))
xx = pd.DataFrame(x_grid.ravel(), columns=["exam1"])
yy = pd.DataFrame(y_grid.ravel(), columns=["exam2"])
z = pd.DataFrame({"intercept" : [1]*xx.shape[0]})
z["exam1"] = xx
z["exam2"] = yy
z = normalize_features(z)
z = map_features(z,mapping_degree)
p = z.apply(lambda row: predict(pd.DataFrame(row)), axis=1)
p = np.array(p.values)
p = p.reshape(x_grid.shape)
plt.scatter(train_data[train_data["admit"] == 0]["exam1"], train_data[train_data["admit"] == 0]["exam2"],marker="o")
plt.scatter(train_data[train_data["admit"] == 1]["exam1"], train_data[train_data["admit"] == 1]["exam2"],marker="x")
plt.contour(x_grid, y_grid, p, levels = [0.5]) #displays only decision boundary
# plt.contour(x_grid, y_grid, p, 50, cmap="RdBu") #display a colored contour
# plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

And below is the boundary I obtain which corresponds to my findings

[image: decision boundary]

This [blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html) explaining the contour function might help.

Comment: can you please share your function used to plot?it will be appreciated.

Comment: @jayant it is present in the code. Look at the last few lines

Comment: Appreciate your response.just a quick question, what does levels=[0.5] mean in contour?does it mean probability of 0.5. I have some idea of contour but not used levels a lot. Second thing, rather than using p (labels 0 or 1) will it be okay to just use p as predicted probabilities