# Python - how to visualise a decision boundary for a LogisticRegression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to visualise a decision boundary for a LogisticRegression() classifier.

But getting a `ValueError: X has 2 features per sample; expecting 24` when calling `plot_boundary(LogisticRegression(), X, y, "Log Reg")`

I've checked the `X.shape` and it is `(14635, 24)`
What could be wrong with my function?

```
def plot_boundary(clf, X, y, plot_title): 
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, 50), np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)) 
    clf.fit(X, y) 
    # plot the decision function for each datapoint on the grid 
    Z = clf.predict_proba(np.vstack((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel())).T)[:, 1] 
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape) 

    image = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', extent=(xx.min(), xx.max(),
                       yy.min(), yy.max()), aspect='auto', origin='lower', 
                       cmap=plt.cm.PuOr_r) 
    contours = plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, levels=[0], linewidths=2, linetypes='--') 
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=30, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired) 
    plt.xticks(()) 
    plt.yticks(()) 
    plt.xlabel(r'$x_1$') 
    plt.ylabel(r'$x_2$') 
    plt.axis([-3, 3, -3, 3]) 
    plt.colorbar(image) 
    plt.title(plot_title, fontsize=12)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample X and y? Without looking into actual data, it's hard to say what exactly is the problem and where is the error coming from

Comment: @Bazingaa I'm using this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/omnamahshivai/surgical-dataset-binary-classification. My target is a 'complication' column from the dataset

Comment: You seem to have quite some experience with asking questions on SO. You have to make sure your code is complete and reproducible. Although people can download the csv file from this link, you should add all the command regarding the loading of the csv file

Comment: This might help your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050906/how-to-plot-the-decision-boundary-of-logistic-regression-in-scikit-learn