# Bad logistic regression in trivial example [scikit-learn]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a trivial example of logistic regression using `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics

# some randomly generated data with two well differentiated groups 
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=15, scale=2, size=(30,1))
y1 = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2, size=(30,1))
x2 = np.random.normal(loc=25, scale=2, size=(30,1))
y2 = np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=2, size=(30,1))

data1 = np.concatenate([x1, y1, np.zeros(shape=(30,1))], axis=1)
data2 = np.concatenate([x2, y2, np.ones(shape=(30,1))], axis=1)

dfa = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=["F1", "F2", "group"])
dfb = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=["F1", "F2", "group"])

df = pd.concat([dfa, dfb], ignore_index=True)

# the actual fitting
features = [item for item in df.columns if item not in ("group")]
logreg = LogisticRegression(verbose=1)
logreg.fit(df[features], df.group)

# plotting and checking the result

theta = logreg.coef_[0,:] # parameters
y0 = logreg.intercept_    # intercept

print("Theta =", theta)
print("Intercept = ", y0)

xdb = np.arange(0, 30, 0.2)  # dummy x vector for decision boundary
ydb = -(y0+theta[0]*xdb) / theta[1] # decision boundary y values

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
colors = {0 : "red", 1 : "blue"}
for i, group in df.groupby("group"):
    plt.plot(group["F1"], group["F2"],
             MarkerFaceColor = colors[i], Marker = "o", LineStyle="",
             MarkerEdgeColor=colors[i])
plt.plot(xdb, ydb, LineStyle="--", Color="b")
```

Shockingly the resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

and, in fact, the accuracy can be calculated:

```
predictions = logreg.predict(df[features])
metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, df["group"])
```

which yielded 0.966...

I must be doing something wrong, just can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what's the desired output? Are you by any chance mixing up logistic regression with linear regression? the former is a classification model, not a regression model despite its name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plotting decision boundary of logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256058/plotting-decision-boundary-of-logistic-regression)

Comment: accuracy is just the number of true positives over the total, so it may be correct in this case. the decision boundary in the picture you have attached shows only two points incorrectly classified, so the classification algorithm seems like a good fit.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something fundamental here but what I was expecting is a straight line, negative slope and crossing the x-axis around x=30 and the y-axis around y=30, for instance. Such line perfectly separates the data into the two labelled group and that's why I thought the problem was _trivial_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to regularization. The best value of line would be with the intercept value of around -16 but due to regularization it is not able reach that level.

Logistic regression minimize the loss function that is combination of error and weight values. In this case when we increase the value of C model will focus more on reducing error (Thus finding better decision boundary) and less on weights. Results in proper decision boundary.

Although regularization is very important in most of the real world scenarios. In some cases it is important not to use one.

Make the following change

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(verbose=1, C=100)
```

The output with this is following
[image]

Read more about regularization to understand this better

Comment: Please explain how regularization is affecting this. Not just regularization, I can achieve same results if I change other parameters like `penalty='l1'`, or `solver='lbfgs'` etc.

Comment: Machine learning not about the trail and error with the parameters. When we increase value of C the importance of finding proper decision boundary is increased and will give less importance weight values. Thus we get better better decision boundary in this case.

Comment: Thats what I am saying to add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; edited the answer. Please  Refrain from downvoting the answer unless answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @KevalDave! I took me a while to realise that increasing C actually means decreasing the penalty on the parameters. As mentioned by @VivekKumar, changing penalty or solver also gives the correct decision boundary, which I don't quite understand at this point. Anyway, I am marking this as the correct answer!