# matplotlib : how to draw a line perfectly dividing my graph into two sections and color them

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Hi so i was trying to implement my svm in python using matplotlib and was able to do so as you can see below 
Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")

def Build_Data_Set(features = ["EstimatedSalary","Age"]):
    data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:\\Users\\sidharth.m\\Desktop\\Project_sid_35352\\Intern_work\\Social_Network_Ads.csv")

    data_df = data_df[:100]

    X = np.array(data_df[features].values)

    y = (data_df["Purchased"]
         .replace("1",0)
         .replace("0",1)
         .values.tolist())

    return X,y

def Analysis():
    X, y = Build_Data_Set()

    clf = svm.SVC(kernel="linear", C=1.0)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    w = clf.coef_[0]
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
    xx = np.linspace(min(X[:, 0]), max(X[:, 0]))
    yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]

    #h0 = plt.plot(xx, yy, "k-", label="age")

    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
    plt.ylabel("Age")
    plt.xlabel("Estimated Salary")
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()


Analysis()
```

Graph:
[graph for svm made using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5339A.png)

Seeing the graph above, how do i effectively draw a line separating the purple and yellow clusters and color the backgrounds so as to show they are different.

Comment: Is this a question about how to draw a separating line and color both parts or how to calculate, which line best separates the two populations? Apart from that, this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you are asking how to draw boundary lines or regions, this link might be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639028/how-to-plot-decision-boundaries-between-3-classes-using-discriminant-functions/48651271#48651271

Comment: @MrT How to calculate which line best separates the two populations.

Comment: @SelçukGülcan It was helpfull thanks! but not exactly what i need, im looking for a way to draw/create a line that perfectly maps itself to seperate the 2 populations. :)

Comment: @MrT alright done. Sorry for any inconvenience im not used to posting on stack overflow.

Comment: Imho a question about cluster analysis will get better answers on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation of the boundary line can be computed by using `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes. Think of equation of the line, `a * x_1 + b * x_2 + c = 0`. Here `a` is `coef_[0][0]`, `b` is `coef_[0][1]` and c is `intercept_`. You may look at the code below to see how this line can be computed and drawn.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

length = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2, 100)
c1 = np.array((length * np.cos(angle), length * np.sin(angle))).T
length = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
angle = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2, 100)
c2 = np.array((2 + length * np.cos(angle), 2 + length * np.sin(angle))).T
X = np.vstack((c1, c2))

y = np.ones(200)
y[100:] = 2
plt.scatter(X[:,0][y==1], X[:,1][y==1])
plt.scatter(X[:,0][y==2], X[:,1][y==2])

from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y) 
print(clf.coef_)
print(clf.intercept_)

x_line = np.linspace(-2, 4, 2)

# I think this line is what you are looking for
y_line = (-1 * clf.intercept_ - clf.coef_[0][0] * x_line) / clf.coef_[0][1]
plt.plot(x_line, y_line)
plt.show()
```

Output :

[image: Plot of SVM decision boundary]

Comment: 'y_line = (-1 * clf.intercept_ - clf.coef_[0][0] * x_line) / clf.coef_[0][1]
plt.plot(x_line, y_line)' was indeed what i was looking for, thanks :)