# scatter data and draw decision boundary in python

Tags: python, plot, scatter

i have this code, i have loaded iris data set, scattered the data into two classes(in a one versus all form) i have designed a single layer perceptron, W_ are the weights and the code for plotting is as followed:

```
x = train_s[: , 1].T
y = train_s[: , 2].T
label = train_t
colors = ['green','blue']
plt.scatter(x, y, c=label, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors))
x1 = np.linspace(4,8)
y1 = np.linspace(1.5,5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
plt.plot([0,W_[1]],[0,W_[2]])
plt.show()
```

But the resulting figure is like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ5xu.png]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cross this plot line : `plt.plot([0,W_[1]],[0,W_[2]])` with your scatter plot?
If so the suppose problem are in this range plot. 
Your scatter plot have this axis ranges:
 X: 4~8
 Y: 1.5~5
But you line plot have the ranges
 X:[0,W_[1]]
 Y:[0,W_[2]]
You should ''normalize'' both ranges to have a good graphical merge.

Comment: which range should i normalize the weights? my weights are 1d and i have x and y dimensions for my scattered data

Comment: I found a complete answer for this plot line (called decision boundary) at this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot

Comment: If your problem was solved, please accept this answer ;)