# AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have used Random Forest Regressor to solve a Regression Problem, Now I want to plot regression Line, According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356267/10342778) answer, I am trying this.

```py
w =  model1.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (model1.intercept_[0]) / w[1]

plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
```

Where model1 is `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` which is already fit on data set. What are some alternatives.

The Error Message is

`AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'`

Comment: If you look at the documentation of [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html). There isn't any `coef_` attribute or `intercept_`

Comment: @skrrrt Is there any way we can get this?

Comment: It looks to me that you are trying to plot the line of prediction using the parameters obtained after fitting a [linear regression model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) which has the `coef_` and `intercept_`

Comment: Yes, but After Fitting the [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) not Linear Regression Model

Answer (score 1):

You will have `coef_` and `intercept_` when the model fits a hyperplane. Linear regression is one such model which fits a hyperplane along the train data such that the deviation/error is minimal. These `coef_` and `intercept_` represents the hyperplane.

However, models like Random Forest do not fit a hyperplane but instead identify a set of decisions based on the input which finally lead to the prediction. You can think of them as a set of nested if else conditions.  So, if your model is a Random forest based then there is no concept of `coef_` and `intercept_` but what you can rather do is to print the decision tree.