# How to extract the boundary values from k-nearest neighbors predict

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, knn

- How can only the boundary values be **extracted**, or returned, from `.predict`, for [`sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)?

### MRE

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# prepare data
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['label'] = y
species_map = dict(zip(range(3), iris.target_names))
df['species'] = df.label.map(species_map)
df = df.reindex(['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)', 'species', 'label'], axis=1)

# instantiate model
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6)

# predict for 'petal length (cm)' and 'petal width (cm)'
knn.fit(df.iloc[:, 2:4], df.label)

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# create colormap for the contour plot
cmap_light = ListedColormap(list(sns.color_palette('pastel', n_colors=3)))

# Plot the decision boundary.
# For that, we will assign a color to each point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = df['petal length (cm)'].min() - 1, df['petal length (cm)'].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = df['petal width (cm)'].min() - 1, df['petal width (cm)'].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = knn.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# add data points
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='petal length (cm)', y='petal width (cm)', hue='species', ax=ax, edgecolor='k')

# add decision boundary countour map
ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light, alpha=0.4)

# legend
lgd = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

### Resulting Plot

[image]

### Desired Plot

- Not the colors, or styles, just that it has only the decision boundary, and the data points.

[image]

### Resources

- [`scikit-learn`: Nearest Neighbors Classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html#nearest-neighbors-classification)
- [`scikit-learn`: Plot the decision boundaries of a VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_voting_decision_regions.html#plot-the-decision-boundaries-of-a-votingclassifier)
- [`scikit-learn`: Comparing Nearest Neighbors with and without Neighborhood Components Analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_nca_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-nca-classification-py)

### SO Question that doesn't answer the question

- [Plotting a decision boundary separating 2 classes using Matplotlib's pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241)

  - This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356267/7758804) shows how to plot the decision boundary without filling the plot, but none of the answers show how to **extract the decision boundary values**.

    - `plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)`

### Self Answered

- I have provided **a** solution, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. I'm certainly open to other options.
- That said, I do not want a solution that is a colored in `contourf`, or `pcolormesh` plot.
- The best solution would, succinctly, extract only the decision boundary values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is one solution that I came up with, which uses [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) along both axes of `Z`, the `.predict` result. The idea being, whenever there is a change in result, that is a decision boundary.

  - Use `.diff` to subtract `Z` from itself, shifted by 1.
  - Create `mask`, using `np.diff(Z) != 0`
  - Use `mask` to select the appropriate `x` and `y` from `xx` and `yy`
- Using the existing code from the OP

```py
# use diff to create a mask
mask = np.diff(Z, axis=1) != 0
mask2 = np.diff(Z, axis=0) != 0

# apply mask against xx and yy
xd = np.concatenate((xx[:, 1:][mask], xx[1:, :][mask2]))
yd = np.concatenate((yy[:, 1:][mask], yy[1:, :][mask2]))

# plot just the decision boundary
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(x=xd, y=yd, color='k', edgecolor='k', s=5, ax=ax, label='decision boundary')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='petal length (cm)', y='petal width (cm)', hue='species', ax=ax, edgecolor='k')
sns.scatterplot(x=xd, y=yd, color='k', edgecolor='k', s=5, ax=ax, label='decision boundary')
lgd = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

### `xd` and `yd` correctly overlay `plt.contourf`

[image]