# How to have multiple categorical markers on a scatterplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scatter-plot

I want to train logistic regression model, and after that create a plot which shows boundary lines, but in specific way.

**My work so far**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import datasets
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

logreg = LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# Create an instance of Logistic Regression Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = logreg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))

plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)
# Plot also the training points

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:,1], c=Y, marker='x',edgecolors='k', cmap=cmap_bold)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length'),
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

[image]

However I find it very unreadable. I want to have other markers for each classification and legend in left upper corner. Just like in the image below :

[image]

Do you have any idea how can I change that ? I played with `marker ='s'`, `marker='x'`, but those change all points on scatter plot, instead of one specific classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are plotting with categorical values, you can just plot each class separately:

```
# Replace this
# plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:,1], c=Y, marker='x',edgecolors='k', cmap=cmap_bold)
# with this

markers = 'sxo'
for m,i in zip(markers,np.unique(Y)):
    mask = Y==i
    plt.scatter(X[mask, 0], X[mask,1], c=cmap_bold.colors[i],
                marker=m,edgecolors='k', label=i)
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- I find it easier to create a dataframe from `X` & `Y`, and then plot the data points with [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

  - [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is a high-level api for matplotlib
  - As shown in [How to extract the boundary values from k-nearest neighbors predict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64398946/7758804), the dataframe columns can be used to specify all data for fitting, and x and y min and max.

### load and setup the data

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # version 3.3.1
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import datasets
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn  # versuin 0.11.0
import pandas  # version 1.1.3

cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

# seaborn.scatterplot palette parameter takes a list
palette = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF']

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

# add X & Y to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris.feature_names[:2])
df['label'] = Y
# map the number values to the species name and add it to the dataframe
species_map = dict(zip(range(3), iris.target_names))
df['species'] = df.label.map(species_map)

logreg = LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# Create an instance of Logistic Regression Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = logreg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
```

### plot the data

```py
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))

plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light, shading='auto')
# Plot also the training points

# add data points using seaborn
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='sepal length (cm)', y='sepal width (cm)', hue='species',
                style='species', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5, palette=palette, s=70)

# change legend location
plt.legend(title='Species', loc=2)

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
# plt.xticks(())
# plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

- `alpha=0.5` is used with `sns.scatterplot`, to show that some values of `'versicolor'` and `'virginica'` overlap.
- If the `species` label is desired for the legend, instead of the name, change `hue='species'` to `hue='label'`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a single call to `plt.scatter` to one call for each marker type, since matplotlib does not allow passing multiple marker types as it does with color.

The plot code becomes something like

```py
# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))

plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)
# Plot also the training points

X0 = X[Y==0]
X1 = X[Y==1]
X2 = X[Y==2]
Y0 = Y[Y==0]
Y1 = Y[Y==1]
Y2 = Y[Y==2]

plt.scatter(X0[:, 0], X0[:,1], marker='s',color="red")
plt.scatter(X1[:, 0], X1[:,1], marker='x',color="blue")
plt.scatter(X2[:, 0], X2[:,1], marker='o',color="green")
plt.xlabel('Sepal length'),
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

where you individually set the marker type and color of each class. You can also create a list for the marker type and another for the color and use a loop.