# Easy way to plot basic SVM in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have the following code which creates some random points and a basic polynomial kernel SVM. It then plots just the points. I want to add the decision boundary/margin to the plot. Any and all input is appreciated!

```
from sklearn import svm
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = []
for _ in range(100):
    X.append([random.randint(0, 101), random.randint(0, 101)])

y = []
for _ in range(100):
    y.append(random.randint(0,1))


svm.SVC(kernel = 'poly').fit(X,y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(X)):
    if y[i] == 0:
        ax.scatter(X[i][0], X[i][1],c = 'red', vmin=0, vmax=100)
    else:
        ax.scatter(X[i][0], X[i][1],c = 'blue', vmin=0, vmax=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/64398946/7758804

Comment: Oh dope, this is way more helpful than any of the other threads I found. Thanks g