# Optimize a boundary line to find maximum precision and ratio of true positives

Tags: python, math, optimization

I have a bunch of true positives (TP) and false positives (FP) in scatterplot. The points are in a N*2 numpy arrays where N= number of observations. I would like to formulate a straight line (y=mx+b) by varying the intercept (b) to split the data in a way that maximizes TPs above the boundary line and Precision (TP/(TP+FP)). The coordinates I get are a result of a Neural Network classifier, please assume these are given and I cannot change the algorithm that produces them.
[image: scatterplot of tps and fps]

code I have so far is:

```
def precision_line(b, m, tp_all_, fp_all_):
  count_tps=tp_all_.shape[0]
  count_fps=fp_all_.shape[0]
  tp_above_line = len(np.where(tp_all_[:,1] >= tp_all_[:,0] * m + b)[0])
  fp_above_line = len(np.where(fp_all_[:,1] >= fp_all_[:,0] * m + b)[0])
  tps = tp_above_line/count_tps
  fps = fp_above_line/count_fps
  precision =tp_above_line/(tp_above_line+fp_above_line)
  return precision, tps, fps
```

but I do not know where to go from there! I want an algorithm where I set some sort of a cost function that automatically optimizes/solves the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by _maximizes TPs above the boundary line and Precision_? Are those two goals? If yes, it's up to you to weigh them up and make a combined _cost function_.

Comment: Can you help with that? I am not sure how to do it

Comment: If you only ask _Can you help_ without answering the questions, I can't.

Comment: Did you do any research? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot/22356551