# plotting a function like ezplot in matlab in python using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning

I have a a classification function that classify a data point into one of two classes. The problem is, I need a way to plot the decision boundary of two class. While this is easy for linear function. it's cumbersome to find the equation of the boundary. ezplot package in matlab seems to be able to do it. It will plot the result automatically. It works using linear and quadratic function. It doesn't require you to provide the coordinate. In matplotlib, you can only plot if you are given the coordinate. Does anyone know how to do this with matplotlib?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting a decision boundary separating 2 classes using Matplotlib's pyplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294241/plotting-a-decision-boundary-separating-2-classes-using-matplotlibs-pyplot)

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054923/plot-decision-boundary-matplotlib